# custom tagging with specific coordinates in pdf?

Tags: pdf, itext, pdfbox, pypdf, pdfminer

I have all the paragraph coordinates of a pdf. like `[[16.88, 767.724, 530.464, 816.638], [27.093, 681.063, 124.125, 709.911], [30.806, 648.372, 124.712, 670.008], [30.806, 620.256, 124.712, 641.892], [30.806, 592.176, 124.712, 613.812], [30.806, 564.096, 124.712, 585.732], [30.806, 536.016, 124.712, 557.652], [30.813, 340.983, 156.693, 369.831], [52.244, 211.098, 129.372, 331.59], [279.891, 397.454, 572.939, 716.682], [302.43, 277.287, 337.13, 311.143], [367.775, 336.464, 402.475, 370.319], [367.803, 278.696, 402.504, 312.551], [438.246, 336.464, 472.947, 370.319], [438.246, 277.287, 472.947, 311.143], [372.366, 214.928, 474.946, 248.783], [517.9, 278.696, 552.6, 312.551], [342.311, 182.842, 535.856, 200.872], [24.657, 44.612, 574.588, 162.24]]`
And the coordinates shows on pdf image like below. 
[image]

I have managed to write algorithm to get the content(coordinates) with the respective tag and order.

What I would want to do is to apply these tags to the source pdf. Based on the order I need to tag the pdf.

- ordered list and unordered list tag with **li**
- paragraph with **P** tag
- chemical equation I need to tag as an image/figure.

Could you please suggest me, any one how I can achieve this.
Please..

Comment: Have you checked whether the text drawing instructions respect your tagging objects? E.g. it is possible that all the CH groups in the center line are drawn by the same **TJ** operator which would make tagging as distinct paragraphs impossible. In such cases you'd have to also split up such operations...